# Why Does My AJAX Response Contain HTML Source?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

hope you're all doing well. Here's the deal. I make an AJAX call to PHP and PHP decodes the JSON string then echoes a property from the json object but in the AJAX response alert, I get the correct value from the json property AND the source of the current page, for example:

```
jsonProperty<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>... [the rest of the page's source]
```

Here is my code:
PHP

```
<?php
private function validate_review(){
    $json = json_decode($_POST['data']);
    echo $json->review;
}
?>
```

AJAX:

```
    <script>
    var reviewData = {
        title : $('#fieldtitle').val(),
        raiting : starRaiting,
        review : $('#fieldreview').val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost/codeigniter/new-review',
        data: {data: JSON.stringify(reviewData)},
        success: function(result){
            alert(result);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Why would the response also include the source of the page, this is completely counter-intuitive and strange. Help?

Comment: use die; or exit; after response code or create a separate file for return response

Comment: it means you have something wrong in your requested page? try to read the html response then you'll get some idea what was it

Answer (score 1):

### Request:

specify your request dataType

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost/codeigniter/new-review',
        data: {data: JSON.stringify(reviewData)},
        dataType: 'jsonp', //tell the server that you expect json 
        success: function(result){
            alert(result);
        }
    });
```

### Response:

```
<?php
//DO NOT echo any output before header
header('Content-Type: application/json'); //said this response content is json
?>
```

and die instead of echo json content

Comment: I know it is an old response, but what to do if you cannot use JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code still includes the template.

```
private function validate_review(){
    $json = json_decode($_POST['data']);
    die($json->review);
}
```

This should work.